# List comprehension difference between python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I need to port an script from python 3 to python 2, the script just take a word and generate all posible segmentations of the words and return the most probable one. When generating the candidates for the segmentation python2 and python3 give very different results. Here is the code I am using:

```
def splits(text, start=0, s=20):
    """Return a list of all (first, rest) pairs; start <= len(first) <= L."""
     return [(text[:i], text[i:])
            for i in range(start, min(len(text), s)+1)]

def __segment__(self, text):
    """Return a list of words that is the most probable segmentation of text."""
    if not text:
        return []
    else:
        candidates = [[first] + self.__segment__(rest)
                      for (first, rest) in splits(text, 1)]
        print(candidates)
        return max(candidates, key=self.p_words)
```

When printing the candidates I get this answers, the word I was trying to segment is 'casadecampo', the results should be 'casa de campo':

**Python2**

```
[[u'o']]
[[u'p', u'o'], [u'po']]
[[u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'mp', u'o'], [u'mpo']]
[[u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'am', u'p', u'o'], [u'amp', u'o'], [u'ampo']]
[[u'c', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'ca', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'cam', u'p', u'o'], [u'camp', u'o'], [u'campo']]
[[u'e', u'c', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'ec', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'eca', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'ecam', u'p', u'o'], [u'ecamp', u'o'], [u'ecampo']]
[[u'd', u'e', u'c', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'de', u'c', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'dec', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'deca', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'decam', u'p', u'o'], [u'decamp', u'o'], [u'decampo']]
[[u'a', u'd', u'e', u'c', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'ad', u'e', u'c', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'ade', u'c', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'adec', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'adeca', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'adecam', u'p', u'o'], [u'adecamp', u'o'], [u'adecampo']]
[[u's', u'a', u'd', u'e', u'c', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'sa', u'd', u'e', u'c', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'sad', u'e', u'c', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'sade', u'c', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'sadec', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'sadeca', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'sadecam', u'p', u'o'], [u'sadecamp', u'o'], [u'sadecampo']]
[[u'a', u's', u'a', u'd', u'e', u'c', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'as', u'a', u'd', u'e', u'c', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'asa', u'd', u'e', u'c', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'asad', u'e', u'c', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'asade', u'c', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'asadec', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'asadeca', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'asadecam', u'p', u'o'], [u'asadecamp', u'o'], [u'asadecampo']]
[[u'c', u'a', u's', u'a', u'd', u'e', u'c', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'ca', u's', u'a', u'd', u'e', u'c', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'cas', u'a', u'd', u'e', u'c', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'casa', u'd', u'e', u'c', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'casad', u'e', u'c', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'casade', u'c', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'casadec', u'a', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'casadeca', u'm', u'p', u'o'], [u'casadecam', u'p', u'o'], [u'casadecamp', u'o'], [u'casadecampo']]
```

The solution I get with this is 'c a s a d e c a m p o'

**Python3**

```
[['o']]
[['p', 'o'], ['po']]
[['m', 'po'], ['mp', 'o'], ['mpo']]
[['a', 'mp', 'o'], ['am', 'po'], ['amp', 'o'], ['ampo']]
[['c', 'amp', 'o'], ['ca', 'mp', 'o'], ['cam', 'po'], ['camp', 'o'], ['campo']]
[['e', 'campo'], ['ec', 'amp', 'o'], ['eca', 'mp', 'o'], ['ecam', 'po'], ['ecamp', 'o'], ['ecampo']]
[['d', 'e', 'campo'], ['de', 'campo'], ['dec', 'amp', 'o'], ['deca', 'mp', 'o'], ['decam', 'po'], ['decamp', 'o'], ['decampo']]
[['a', 'de', 'campo'], ['ad', 'e', 'campo'], ['ade', 'campo'], ['adec', 'amp', 'o'], ['adeca', 'mp', 'o'], ['adecam', 'po'], ['adecamp', 'o'], ['adecampo']]
[['s', 'a', 'de', 'campo'], ['sa', 'de', 'campo'], ['sad', 'e', 'campo'], ['sade', 'campo'], ['sadec', 'amp', 'o'], ['sadeca', 'mp', 'o'], ['sadecam', 'po'], ['sadecamp', 'o'], ['sadecampo']]
[['a', 'sade', 'campo'], ['as', 'a', 'de', 'campo'], ['asa', 'de', 'campo'], ['asad', 'e', 'campo'], ['asade', 'campo'], ['asadec', 'amp', 'o'], ['asadeca', 'mp', 'o'], ['asadecam', 'po'], ['asadecamp', 'o'], ['asadecampo']]
[['c', 'as', 'a', 'de', 'campo'], ['ca', 'sade', 'campo'], ['cas', 'a', 'de', 'campo'], ['casa', 'de', 'campo'], ['casad', 'e', 'campo'], ['casade', 'campo'], ['casadec', 'amp', 'o'], ['casadeca', 'mp', 'o'], ['casadecam', 'po'], ['casadecamp', 'o'], ['casadecampo']]
```

The solution with this one is 'casa de campo'.

Why do I get different solutions for python 2 and 3?

EDIT: Added "splits" function

Comment: So your question is...

Comment: you're not too far from a [mcve]. Remove the self stuff, create an input and make a program that runs without external data or user interaction.

Comment: Did you compare the results of `splits` between the two versions of Python?

Comment: the output you're seeing (the 'u' prefix) is unicode. The difference is normal. I'd have expected to see some code testing against `str` type (that could be a difference) but I don't see any.

Comment: I know the u is for unicode, my prblem is the resultant lists, in the case of python3 I don't get any separation of individual characters.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, it has to be with the integer division in python2, it considered all the probabilities 0, since I did int/int. Change the code to do float/int.